# Multiple Where Clause Based On Passed Parameters in Laravel5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to achieve what this query does in my controller

```
select * from table where true
if($param1 != ""){
  and table.column1 = '$param1'
}
if($param2 != ""){
  and table.column2 = '$param2'
}
```

So far what i have tried is

```
function seachpullethouse(Request $request){
    $searchcode = $request->code;     
    $mpullethouse = DB::table('mpullethouses')->query();

    if(!empty($searchcode)){
        $query ->Where('mpullethouses.code','like','%'.$searchcode.'%');
    }

    $query ->select('mpullethouses.*')->get();
    return response()->json(['mpullethouse'=>$mpullethouse]);
}
```

but it seems it is wrong...Can pls anyone help me??...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `when` for this.

```
public function seachpullethouse(Request $request)
{
    $searchcode = $request->code;

    $mpullethouse = DB::table('mpullethouses')
        ->when($searchcode, function ($query) use ($searchcode) {
            return $query->where('code', 'like', "%{$searchcode}%");
        })
        ->get();

    return response()->json(['mpullethouse' => $mpullethouse]);
}
```

For more info check https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#conditional-clauses

Comment: Thx bro..U save my day :)